# Target every two elements - Javascript / jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, list

I'm struggling with a piece of code in js.

I have a table and I want to iterate over it and do something for the first two tr's, than for the third and fourth etc. To make it cleaner I'll write it here as a list.

Let's say I want to give one class for every two elements.
Like this:

```
<li></li> <!-- class1-->
<li></li> <!-- class1-->
<li></li> <!-- class2-->
<li></li> <!-- class2-->
<li></li> <!-- class3-->
<li></li> <!-- class3-->
<li></li> <!-- class4-->
<li></li> <!-- class4-->
etc ..
```

I was thinking about a for loop but I can't figure out how to target every two. Also I've found ' slice ' But that seems like you can select items between two other items.
I wanted to make a while loop that changes the values of start and end in the slice but cannot think of a good way to do this.

Is there something for this ?

Comment: Please share the _piece of code in js_

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child

Comment: Really unclear, so you want to loop every two and do what?

Comment: @maartje are you adding classes just for write css, if yes, than you use nth-child in css and no need to add classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add classes to the `table` `tr` elements by iterating over them using jQuery:

```
var i = 1;
var sumupi = 0;

jQuery("table tr").each(function(){
    jQuery(this).addClass('class-' + i);
    if (sumupi == 1) {
        i++;
        sumupi = 0;
    }
    else {
        sumupi = 1;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can loop `li` elements and use `index` and remainder operator `%` to get every `nth` element and do something.

```js
let c = 1;

$("li").each(function(i) {
  $(this).attr('class', 'class' + c).text(c)
  if ((i - 1) % 2 == 0) c++;
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
```

Answer (score 0):

not sure what precisely you are up to, but maybe a loop like this can help.

```
for(let i=0; i<list.length; i+=2){
    doSomething(list[i], getSpecialParam(i/2));
    doSomething(list[i+1], getSpecialParam(i/2));
}
```

when making the runs larger your may want to nest loops

```
for(let i=0; i<list.length; i+=runLength){
    for(let j=0; j<runLength; j+=1){
        doSomething(list[i+j], getSpecialParam(i/runLength));
    }
}
```

```js
const list = $('li');
const letters = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';

const runLength = 2;

for(let i=0; i<list.length; i+=runLength){
  for(let j=0; j<runLength; j++){
    list[i+j].textContent = letters[(i/runLength)%letters.length];
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
<ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want configuration based breakup of elements  use length=2 or whatever you want. you will get sub array with the desired length

```js
var items=$("li"),index=1,length=2;
 while(items.length) {    
    $(items.splice(0,length)).each(function() {
       $(this).addClass('class'+index).text('class'+index);      
  });
   index+=1;
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
```